# QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'MyConnection' error

Tags: c++, sql, database, qt, runtime-error

I have written a Qt program in c++ inorder to access a database and load database tables to table view! My program does not show any compile errors but gives 2 runtime errors

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'MyConnection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'MyConnection', old connection removed.
```

There are mainly to classes namely MainWindow(Has database connection methods) and Dialog
Following are my codes

**MainWindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public: QSqlDatabase mydb;
        bool conOpen(QString userName,QString password,QString hostname,int port,QString service){
            mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI","MyConnection");
            mydb.setUserName(userName);
            mydb.setPassword(password);
            mydb.setHostName(hostname);
            mydb.setPort(port);
            mydb.setDatabaseName(service);
            return mydb.open();

}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog *dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
   if(conOpen(ui->uname->text(),ui->pword->text(),ui->ip->text(),ui->port->text().toInt(),ui->service->text())){

        dialog1->show();
}
```

**Dialog.h**

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
```

**Dialog.cpp**

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QSqlQueryModel *modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
    if(QSqlDatabase::contains("MyConnection")){

        QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase::database("MyConnection"));
        qry->prepare("select NAME FROM Employees");
           qry->exec();
        modal->setQuery(*qry);
      ui->tableView->setModel(modal);

    }
}
```

The MainWindow form is used for login and Dialog form is used to retrieve entries in  database table to a table view
How can I correct the issue?

Comment: Do you press that button more than once?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto yeah! I pressed the button in MainWindow several times but the problem is that dialog1 does not appear though I press the button :(

Comment: That's the problem. `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase` isn't meant to be called more that once.

Comment: yeah but why doesn't dialog1 appear when I click the button? :(

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program? Is `dialog1->show();` called the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase) is a static function and every time you call it, it will create a connection instance. So if your app is designed to establish only a single connection to database server, you should not call it more that once.

> **QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(const QString &type, const QString &connectionName = QLatin1String( defaultConnection ))**
>
> Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver
>   type and the connection name `connectionName`. If there already exists a
>   database connection called `connectionName`, that connection is removed.

You may need to move the logic of opening database code (including `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase`) to somewhere that gets called only once throughout the entire app.

Comment: Thanx! The problem is dialog1 not appearing when I click the button! But why doen't it appear?

Comment: @KushanPeiris Return value of `conOpen` may be `false`.